# Oracle database is returning date as 1951 instead of 2051

Tags: database, oracle, date, oracle11g

Hi i am using an input field to enter date in UI and enters as `02/01/2051`. It will save into the database as `01-FEB-51`, i am using `DATE` as the datatype. When i am fetching it is returning as `01-feb-1951`. Below is the query i am using

```
select to_date(LN_MAT_DT,'dd/mm/YYYY') from Emp ;
```

Can some one please help on this.

Comment: If it is date data type then why you are using to_date to fetch it. It is already a date. Simply use `select ln_mat_dt from emp`

Comment: **NEVER**, ever call `to_date()` on a value that is already a date. That will first convert the `date` value to a `varchar` just to convert that `varchar` back to a `date` which it was to begin with.

Comment: OK will use fetch the column results directly, i won't use to_char/to_date. It will return 01-FEB-51. So now how to show this as 02/01/2051 in the screen.

Comment: To show the data in the format you want, use to_char on date column. Or set nls_date_format as dd/mm/yyyy for your session

Comment: Eventhough i am altering the nls_date_format still i am getting that 1951 only.

Comment: What tool do you use to enter data into database? And what do you use to fetch data?

Comment: With screenshots and the code (if available), please

Answer (score 0):

It is about format mask you use and differences between `RRRR` and `YYYY`. Have a look at the following example:

```
SQL> select to_date('01.02.51', 'dd.mm.yy') date_yy,
  2         to_date('01.02.51', 'dd.mm.rr') date_rr,
  3         --
  4         to_date('01.02.1951', 'dd.mm.yyyy') date_19_yyyy,
  5         to_date('01.02.1951', 'dd.mm.rrrr') date_19_rrrr,
  6         --
  7         to_date('01.02.2051', 'dd.mm.yyyy') date_20_yyyy,
  8         to_date('01.02.2051', 'dd.mm.rrrr') date_20_rrrr
  9  from dual;

DATE_YY    DATE_RR    DATE_19_YY DATE_19_RR DATE_20_YY DATE_20_RR
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
01.02.2051 01.02.1951 01.02.1951 01.02.1951 01.02.2051 01.02.2051

SQL>
```

What you should do is to use 4-digits year with the `YYYY` format mask.

Comment: I may not use YYYY format now s it was already designed. I am getting the result as 01.02.2051 only when i am altering the session like below. Alter SESSION SET nls_date_format = 'dd-mm-yyyy'; But still this not working when i am fetching from my table

Comment: Sounds to me like the issue is when you initially insert the data.  The data type DATE _always_ has 4-digit year, plush month, day, hour, minute, and second. I'll bet that your INSERT is not specifying 4-digit year.  Probably using the RR mask.  Your 'already designed' is fatally flawed.

Comment: i am not splitting the value, i am passing the value as 
02/01/2075.

Answer (score 0):

SInce LN_MAT_DT is DATE datatype, you need to_char, not to_date, ie:

```
select to_char(LN_MAT_DT,'dd/mm/YYYY') from Emp ;
```

Comment: This is not working. I cannot change the design of Database or Altering the session. Does anyone have a solution, please suggest.